# Use FIT to calculate regression line from two sets of data

Tags: webmathematica

I figure out how to figure out the regression line using fit {I need to use FIT} for one set of number. However, I have to combine two sets and figure out the regression line.

```
 numberset1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
 numberset2 = {6,5,6,7,8}
```

I am doing this to figure out the regression line for the first set.

```
 line = Fit[numberset1, {1, x}, x]
```

Then I graph both sets in a scatter plot with the regression line for set 1. However, I need to use both sets to figure out one regression line.
I tried doing this

```
 data = {numberset1, numberset2}
 Then 

  line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
```

but this does not work
Ive also tried

```
  line = Fit[{numberset1,numberset2}, {1, x}, x]
```

did not work

Any ideas, I've already looked at the FIT line documentation in mathematica. None of the examples work.

Comment: Why not `line = Fit[Join[numberset1,numberset2], {1, x}, x]` ? Also, please clarify what are `data2` and `data1` in your code.

Comment: Or maybe you need `Fit[Transpose[{numberset1, numberset2}], {1, x}, x]` ?

Answer (score 2):

The way the question is phrased you have two lists that need to be joined and then apply a linear fit to the joined list.

To join them use:

```
data = Join[numberset1, numberset2]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8} *)
```

Now apply `Fit` to the `data`

```
line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
(* 0.8 + 0.709091 x *)
```

The answer is approximatly to `0.71*x + 0.8`.

Note that data in this form input to `Fit` assumes that the `x` input equals `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and the `y` output is the `data`.

Another function that can be used for fitting is `LinearmodelFit`

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An advantage of this approach is that you have access to all sorts of valuable statistical information on the data and fit (see documentation).

To compare the data to the fit the linear model `lm` can be used as a function.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],
 Plot[lm[x], {x, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]